# Unable to compile typescript with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I would like to debug my node js app written in typescript.
I have this script.

`"start": "nodemon --exec node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/index.ts ",`

Debugger is listening so it seems working but
What I am getting is
`TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:`

This was source origin working script but I need attach debugger.
`nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/index.ts`

Comment: Any specific reason on changing the `ts-node` to `ts-node/register` in you debug command?

Comment: ts-node not recognizing --inspect or --inspect-brk switch

Comment: Did you try using the `--inspect-brk` flag instead of the `--inspect`?

Comment: I have tried but debugger has none Network tab in source, no other files except index.ts are available and after some time it throws TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:

Comment: Change file encoding to UTF-8.